# What is a secret option and how would I use it in real project (NodeJS/Express)

Tags: node.js, session, express, mongoose, cryptography

I'm working on an application with custom authentication where I use session for storing id, but when using `express-session` `middleware` it requires me to input `secret` option - what is it for, and how would I sign it in real world applications?

Comment: If you are referring to the expressjs secret, it is used for signing the cookie ID...also referenced here https://github.com/expressjs/session.

Comment: There are examples of use, but there are no examples of use in real world

Comment: It's kinda hard to post examples of real world usage here, and asking for sample code is explicitly off topic.

Comment: Well, that's not an answer